# daylight saving time and timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, dst

I have IANA time zone identifiers (America/New_York),long,lat, and timestamp. 
With this in mind, I would like to call this

```
`$times = $this->prayTime->getPrayerTimes($current_day, $this->lat, $this->long, $this->timeZone);`
```

But this script doesn't account for dst. So how can I incorporate dst in when calling this script. 
Note: $this->timeZone is in numbers (-4,-3,-5, etc)...

Comment: Post the part of the code where you call `getTransitions`.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983

Comment: The fatal error should give you a line number. Post the code on that line.

Comment: Hey, I really would like to help you, but you're not making it easy and I have better things to do.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the StackOverflow Help Center.  Help us help you and you will get much better results here.  Thanks.